# Execute a list of process without multiprocessing pool map

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #pool = mp.Pool(M)

    p1 = mp.Process(target= target1, args= (arg1,))
    p2 = mp.Process(target= target2, args= (arg1,))
    ...
    p9 = mp.Process(target= target9, args= (arg9,))
    p10 = mp.Process(target= target10, args= (arg10,))
    ...
    pN = mp.Process(target= targetN, args= (argN,))

    processList = [p1, p2, .... , p9, p10, ... ,pN]
```

I have N different target functions which consume unequal non-trivial amount of time to execute.

I am looking for a way to execute them in parallel such that M (1 < M < N) processes are running simultaneously. And as soon as a process is finished next process should start from the list, until all the processes in `processList` are completed.

As I am not calling the same target function, I could not use `Pool`.

I considered doing something like this:

```
    for i in range(0, N, M):
        limit = i + M
        if(limit > N):
            limit = N
        for p in processList[i:limit]:
            p.join()
```

Since my target functions consume unequal time to execute, this method is not really efficient.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Question title has been changed to 'Execute a list of process without multiprocessing pool map' from 'Execute a list of process without multiprocessing pool'.

Comment: You could rearrange your code to have only one target.

Comment: Yes, rearranging could solve the problem. I am reluctant to do that because my targets belong to different modules and it is a part of a 'big' project. Thank you @BenjaminToueg!

Comment: You can do this using a pool. Having different functions only precludes you from using `Pool.map`. See Gill Bates answer.

Comment: I only now noticed that you asking `...without multiprocessing pool`, why you have this requirement? You will end up implementing your own pool or executor with a queue.

Comment: do you need to "replace" the pool's logic ?

Comment: @GillBates I did not know about `apply_async`, so I wrongly assumed that this is not possible with `Pool`.
@Udy No. I am not looking to replace `Pool`. I was just looking for an elegant/pythonic way to solve this problem.
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in Python 3.4, which could be adapted for Python 2.7 :

```
targets_with_args = [
    (target1, arg1),
    (target2, arg2),
    (target3, arg3),
    ...
]

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(target, arg) for target, arg in targets_with_args]
    results = [future.result() for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [proccess Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

from multiprocessing import Pool
import random
import time


def target_1():
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2))
    print('done target 1')

def target_2():
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2))
    print('done target 1')

def target_3():
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2))
    print('done target 1')

def target_4():
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2))
    print('done target 1')


pool = Pool(2) # maximum two processes at time.
pool.apply_async(target_1)
pool.apply_async(target_2)
pool.apply_async(target_3)
pool.apply_async(target_4)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Pool is created specifically for what you need to do - execute many tasks in limited number of processes.

I also suggest you take a look at [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) library and it's [backport to Python 2.7](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures). It has a [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor), which has roughly same capabilities, but it's methods returns [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects) objects, and they has a nicer API.

Comment: This seems to be a better solution than using a single function.

Comment: See my answer for `ProcessPoolExecutor`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Queue`. adding processes to it from `processList`, and as soon as a process is finished i would remove it from the queue and add another one.

a pseudo code will look like:

```
from Queue import Queue
q = Queue(m)

# add first process to queue
i = 0
q.put(processList[i])
processList[i].start()
i+=1

while not q.empty():
    p=q.get()

    # check if process is finish. if not return it to the queue for later checking
    if p.is_alive():
        p.put(t)

    # add another process if there is space and there are more processes to add
    if not q.full() and i < len(processList):
        q.put(processList[i])
        processList[i].start()
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to wrap the functions target{1,2,...N} into a single function forward_to_target that forwards to the appropriate target{1,2,...N} function according to the argument that is passed in. If you cannot infer the appropriate target function from the arguments you currently use, replace each argument with a tuple (argX, X), then in the forward_to_target function unpack the tuple and forward to the appropriate function indicated by the X.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two `list`s of targets and arguments, `zip` the two together - and send them to a runner function (here it's `run_target_on_args`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing as mp

# target functions
targets = [len, str, len, zip]

# arguments for each function
args = [["arg1"], ["arg2"], ["arg3"], [["arg5"], ["arg6"]]]

# applies target function on it's arguments
def run_target_on_args(target_args):
    return target_args[0](*target_args[1])

pool = mp.Pool()
print pool.map(run_target_on_args, zip(targets, args))
```